# Efficiency of conditional statements in Java

Tags: java

```
if(someBoolean && StringUtils.isBlank(someString)){
}
```

or

```
if(StringUtils.isBlank(someString) && someBoolean){
}
```

Which of these is better in terms of efficiency? Will not be the first one faster in execution than the second way of coding? If yes, is it substantially notable?

Comment: I think `1+2 = 2+1` this is logic :)

Comment: Depends on the frequency on the boolean in your input. Likely it wouldn't matter.

Comment: Considering the booleans need not require any further processing for short-circuiting, why not efficient?

Comment: It would likely not matter at all. I think in case you're not doing millions of this statement in a short matter of time, it will not have any affect at all.

Comment: @MohamedAneesA if you already know the answer to your question, why ask it on a Q/A forum? ;)

Comment: Was just curious to know it from experienced programmers..am just a newbie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&&` operator will short circuit, meaning that if the left operand is `false`, the right operand is not evaluated at all. I can't imagine a situation where testing the boolean is more expensive than a call to `isBlank`. On the other hand, if `someString` is a very long string of white space characters (or has a very long white space  prefix), that could be considerably more expensive than testing the boolean. Go with the boolean test on the left.

The only time this loses is when `someBoolean` is `true` and `isBlank` returns `false`. But the loss is minuscule (the cost of testing the boolean) and unless that combination happens an overwhelming percentage of the time, the efficiencies gained will far outweigh the losses.

Answer (score 0):

It does matter depending on if one or the other failed.  When you use logical operators, if one of the checks fail it will, depending on the operator specified, short cut out of the evaluation.  However, assuming those checks always pass, then no there would be no difference in the code you posted.

Whatever the case, as others have pointed out, the difference would be small but not non-existant, and most likely be statistically insignificant.